# setFixedSize() for QMainWindow doesn't work at all

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, qt5

In UI-file I've set size policy for main window as Fixed for both height and width, I've also set both minimum and maximum sizes (for example) to 800*800 and I've written this line of code:

```
w.setFixedSize(800, 800);
```

to `main.cpp` where `w` is an instance of my main window class.

Everything else is default. The project is created as Qt Widgets Application.

So, after all these steps Qt creates a window that doesn't fit the size I mentioned and I still can resize it. What am I doing wrong?

OS: Windows 10; Qt: 5.11.1; Compiler: MSVC 2017

**UPD:**

The problem is actual for both x86 and x64 versions.

Build Steps for 32bit:

`qmake: qmake.exe Calculator.pro -spec winrt-x86-msvc2017 "CONFIG+=qtquickcompiler"`

`Make: jom.exe in D:\Qt Projects\build-Calculator-Qt_5_11_1_for_UWP_32bit_MSVC_2017-Release`

Clean Steps:

`Make: jom.exe clean in D:\Qt Projects\build-Calculator-Qt_5_11_1_for_UWP_32bit_MSVC_2017-Release`

And [a link](https://gist.github.com/unterumarmung/01ddec9a4348c0a1bc2349f52b13d58c) to a gist which contains all files of the project

Also, I have two identical warnings:

```
warning: winrt_manifest_install.path is not defined: install target not created
```

Comment: `QMainWindow::setFixedSize` works like a charm. I've created a new project and added `w.setFixedSize(800, 800);` before `w.show();` and I've got an unresizable 800x800 window. The problem must be somewhere else. Edit your question to provide more details.

Comment: I don't know what details I should provide. Please, help me, I'm a total newbie...

Comment: I would like to help you and in order to do so, I should see more from your project. You have decided, that `setFixedSize` is the problem and it is not. In order to search for the real problem, there should be something in which to search. Why don't you share your code through github for example. When the problem is found, then you could post the problematic part as part of your question.

Comment: I updated the question, I hope it'll help

Comment: if you want help you must provide a [mcve]

Comment: How can I provide a Complete and Verifiable example if it was my first Qt program and if I don't know where the problem comes from?

Comment: @Dan, I've downloaded your project, compiled it and it produces and empty, unresizable 800x800 window.

Comment: So, the problem is in my PC. But where can it be?

Comment: In order for a problem to be fixed, it should be reproducible.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with your graphics driver.